# Laravel 5.2 `composer update` broke my app running under Laravel/Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I was trying to incorporate redis to my Laravel app after learning about it.

And since it is not enabled by default, i've added a line at `composer.json` file with this: `"predis/predis": "1.1.1"` under the `require`.

Next thing i did was run `composer update` from my CLI.

Once that was done i got this post update:

[image]

Then I visit my app page and got this error.

[image]

So I looked on my `app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php` since it was the line it was referring into and went to check if this files still exists but it was not there anymore.

`app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests; <-this
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests; <-this
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources; <-this

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

EDIT: **Solved**
@ceejayoz thank for poiting that out. the downgrade was what caused it. change the 5.2.0. to 5.2.39 and did composer update that now it's back. I was not aware of my own laravel version since i was just using homestead and it was the default values on the `composer.json` file. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you provide your whole `composer.json`? Look at the update results. Several libraries got downgraded, including Laravel itself from 5.2.39 to 5.2.0.

Comment: hi! yes here it is: http://pastebin.com/xrwp2QBX

Comment: and i did `php artisan make:auth` to start my app before, if that makes sense to this issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank for poiting that out. the downgrade was what caused it. change the 5.2.0. to 5.2.39 and did `composer update` that now it's back. I was not aware of my own laravel version since i was just using homestead and it was the default values on the `composer.json` file. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that helped! In the future, you don't have to do a whole `composer update` (which will often get new versions of many different packages) to install a new package. `composer require predis/predis` will fetch just that package (and automatically pick a version that works with your other packages - specifying just 1.1.1 means you don't get bugfixes when you update).